# is possible use method "echo"? i already search and methos is only GET,POST,PUT,DELETE

Tags: javascript, methods, echo

i need make API server with result JSON below

given the **request**:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "method": "echo",
  "params": { "message": "Hello World" }
}
```

and it will give this **response**:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "result": { "message": "Hello World" }
}
```

is it possible to use the method **"`ECHO`"**?

I already search and method is only GET, POST,PUT, DELETE

Comment: You're asking if you can invent your own HTTP verb?

Comment: i want send request with method "echo" is posible?

Comment: The methods you mentioned are the standard ones, you can create your own but there is no guarantee browsers/servers/etc will understand or handle it correctly